# Merge multiple JSON object into a single in Laravel Eloquent collection

Tags: php, json, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm having an issue with merging multiple JSON object into a single with the Laravel Eloquent collection.

When I run the following code:

`return Project::all();`

I got this:

```
[
    {
        "created_at": "2016-02-17 15:08:11",
        "description": "first description",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "updated_at": "2016-02-17 15:08:11"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2016-02-17 15:08:31",
        "description": "second description",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "updated_at": "2016-02-17 15:08:31"
    }
]
```

However, I'm trying to merge this multiple JSON object into a single like the following:

```
{
    "0": "John Doe",
    "1": "Jane Doe"
}
```

This driving my crazy. Is there anyone can assist how may I achieve this? *The key is not important here.*

Comment: how do u want the output to be?

Comment: I want the output to be JSON format.

Comment: can you give the structure pls

Comment: I already did on the above.
```{
    "0": "John Doe",
    "1": "Jane Doe",
    "2": "Joe Doe"
}```

Comment: Can you explain from where did you get these names?

Comment: I got this names from the database with this: `return Projects::all();`. I've edited the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Collection::pluck()`:

```
$projects = Project::all();
$projects = $projects->pluck('name')->toJson();

// [ "John Doe", "Jane Doe" ]
```

If you want to make it an object, cast it like this

```
(object) $projects->pluck('name')->toArray()

// { "0": "John Doe", "1": "Jane Doe" }
```

If you want to return a JSON response

```
$projects = (object) $projects->pluck('name')->toArray()
return response()->json($projects);
```

Comment: This return the name like this: `["John Doe","Jane Doe"]`. However, I'll need the data like this: `{"0": "John Doe", "1": "Jane Doe"}`

Comment: @MdMazedulIslamKhan, i edited my answer. Please check

Comment: This still doesn't work as you can't return an object like this: `(object) $projects->pluck('name')->toArray()`. It return an error: `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.`

Comment: `return response()->json((object) $projects->pluck('name')->toArray());` ,@MdMazedulIslamKhan

Answer (score 0):

Just define a new array an insert whatever values you want.

Suppose your JSON object called $data;

```
    $result = array();
    foreach($data as $us){
      array_push($result, $us['name']);
    }
    $result = json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: This would be return an array still. However, I want to return a JSON